# Как узнать сколько осталось до нового года?

Tags: python, python-3.x, дата, datetime

Как можно узнать сколько осталось дней до нового года на. Языке программирования пайтон? В числовом формате чтоб можно было вывести на экран такое сообщение: до нового года осталось сколько то дней.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import datetime


now = datetime.datetime.today()
NY = datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1)
d = NY-now  
                    
mm, ss = divmod(d.seconds, 60)
hh, mm = divmod(mm, 60)

print('До нового года: {} дней {} часа {} мин {} сек.'.format(d.days, hh, mm, ss))
```

Comment: Не особо шарю в питоне, но думаю как и в других языках, можно константу 2021 заменить на что-то типа ```now.year + 1```, чтобы уж код вышел универсальным