# Как сделать телеграм бота, который будет будет говорить сколько осталось до Нового года/лета/дня рождения? Как прочитатьъ сообщение пользователя?

Tags: python, telebot

````
from datetime import datetime

bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def main (message):
    if message.text == '/new_year' or 'нг':
        msg = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Ввведите дату в формате 'dd-mm-yyyy':")
        test_date = bot.register_next_step_handler(callback=msg)
        now = datetime.now()
        then = datetime.strptime(test_date, "%d-%m-%Y")
        delta1 = datetime(now.year, then.month, then.day)
        delta2 = datetime(now.year + 1, then.month, then.day)

        result = ((delta1 if delta1 > now else delta2) - now).days
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'до вашего дня рождения осталось {result} дней')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'yehjafnkcdm')

bot.polling()```
````

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как узнать сколько осталось до нового года?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1223629/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0)